# Accessing parent object upon detecting a change in just a sub node value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an `Order` node and a `Status` key under that. I am looking for changes in the `Status`’s value and if there’s any change detected, I have to `read` the parent `Order` Node.

The key point is I do not want to listen to changes in the `Order` node. But just the `Status` under the `Order` node. What is the most optimum way to do this? Is it good to have a listener inside another listener? Here's my code:

```
 final Query qRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("orders").orderByChild("customerId").equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .limitToFirst(1);
    qRef.keepSynced(true);

    final DatabaseReference reference = qRef.getRef().child("status");


    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            DatabaseReference inner = reference.getParent();

            inner.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot parent) {
                    if (parent != null) {
                        Order newOrder = parent.getValue(Order.class);
                        if (newOrder != null) {
                            if (newOrder.getStatus() != null && !newOrder.getStatus().equals("FX_OVER"))
                                processOrder(newOrder);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
```

And the JSON:

```
{   "20161010210955" : {
    "createdAt" : {
      "date" : 10,
      "day" : 1,
      "hours" : 21,
      "minutes" : 9,
      "month" : 9,
      "seconds" : 55,
      "time" : 1476113995244,
      "timezoneOffset" : -330,
      "year" : 116
    },
    "customerId" : "npsd3Ldfsdf1x0hsdfsdf2mj14VUA876f2",
    "id" : "20161010210955",
    "status" : "FX_FULL"

  } }
```

Comment: If you're having problems getting code to work, show the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this case a small snippet of your JSON (as text, no screenshot) would also help.

Comment: Thanks. I have added my code to the Question. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you check status first? You know the value of status at beginning. I think this solution should be optimum way.

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if("FX_OVER".equals(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class)) {

            reference.getParent().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot parent) {
                    // This is a defensive check. I dont know this is necessary.
                    // If status exist, parent must be exist.
                    if (parent.exists()) {
                        Order newOrder = parent.getValue(Order.class);
                        if (newOrder != null) {
                            processOrder(newOrder);
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: After I posted the question, i ended up using a solution similar to your answer. Thanks!